# Merge/Coalesce two namedtuples in Python

Tags: python, namedtuple, null-coalescing-operator

I have a `namedtuple` with some default values, and I'd like to merge (or field-wise coalesce) it with another instance of the same `namedtuple`

```
T = collections.namedtuple("T", ("a", "b"))

x = T(1, None)
y = T(None, 1)
z = coalesce(x, y)  # same as z = T(1, 1)
```

Is there a clean way to do this? What I'd *really* like to do is a type-safe `_replace()` call, but this can't exist, so merging seemed like the next best solution.

Comment: I don't understand your second example.

Comment: I was going to say override the previous value, but then it would just return the second parameter. I'll remove the second example.

Comment: What do you mean by "a type-safe `_replace` call?"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `_replace()` is type-annotated as taking something like `Mapping[str, Any]`, so there's no way for mypy to make verify that the kwargs are fields in the `namedtuple`.

Answer (score 3):

```
def coalesce(cls, *tups):
    if any(not isinstance(tup, cls) for tup in tups):
        raise ValueError(f"At least one input is not a {cls}")
    return cls(*(next((x for x in z if x is not None), None) for z in zip(*tups)))
```

I'm  not very happy with this, but it works.

```
x = T(1, None)
y = T(None, 1)
z = coalesce(T, x, y)  # same as z = T(1, 1)
```

We zip together the input tuples and take the first non-`None` value for each position, then build a new instance. You could also take the type of one of the input tuples instead of passing the class.

Comment: Depending on the exact behavior desired, you could remove ` is not None` and just use truthiness.

Comment: Factor out a function `f` that returns the first non-None value of its arguments, then `coalesce` simply  becomes `def coalesce(cls, *tups): return cls(*map(f, *tups))`.

Comment: Where `f = lambda *values: next((x for x in values if x is not None), None)`.

Comment: I like it. You could remove `cls` from the call and do `tup[0].__class__(...)`. You could even remove the `isinstance` check be more duck-type friendly.